# Why is my console printing the same date and not updating like the html

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

This is my first question on stackoverflow. I am currently learning react and I tried to make a live clock which updates every second. I managed to accomplish the html updating through a `useState()` hook and a `useEffect()` hook. Now, I tried printing the current time into the Console when it updates but the console only shows the time when the site was refreshed the last time.

Result: HTML keeps updating correctly but the console stays on the same time.

Could someone explain to me what I am doing wrong or what is the cause to this bug?

Clock.js:

```
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function Clock() {
    const [dateState, setDateState] = useState(new Date());

    function updateFunc(){
        setDateState(new Date());
        console.log(dateState.toLocaleString('eu-DE', {
            second: 'numeric',
            minute: 'numeric',
            hour: 'numeric',
         }));
        
    }

    useEffect(() => {
           setInterval(() => updateFunc(), 1000);
    }, []);
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <p>
              {' '}
              {dateState.toLocaleDateString('eu-DE', {
                 day: 'numeric',
                 month: 'short',
                 year: 'numeric',
              })}
            </p>
            <p>
             {dateState.toLocaleString('eu-DE', {
                hour: 'numeric',
                minute: 'numeric',
                second: 'numeric',
                hour12: false,
            })}
            </p>
        </div>
    );
}    

  export default Clock;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaking, since the `useEffect` has no dependencies, the callback  never changes. The callback has its own scope and the variables (`dateState`)  that's why it never changes.

> If you pass an empty array ([]), the props and state inside the effect will always have their initial values

[source](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#:%7E:text=If%20you%20pass%20an%20empty%20array%20(%5B%5D)%2C%20the%20props%20and%20state%20inside%20the%20effect%20will%20always%20have%20their%20initial%20values)

The solution is to add `updateFunc` to the `useEffect` dependencies list. Then you will need to wrap `updateFunc` with `useCallback` with `dateState` as a dependency.

Note: When the component subscribes to an endless handler (e.g. `setInterval` or socket) it's better to unsubscribe using the [cleanup function](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup).

```js
function Clock() {
  const [dateState, setDateState] = useState(new Date());

  const updateFunc = useCallback(() => {
    setDateState(new Date());
    console.log(
      dateState.toLocaleString("eu-DE", {
        second: "numeric",
        minute: "numeric",
        hour: "numeric"
      })
    );
  }, [dateState]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => updateFunc(), 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [updateFunc]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>
        {" "}
        {dateState.toLocaleDateString("eu-DE", {
          day: "numeric",
          month: "short",
          year: "numeric"
        })}
      </p>
      <p>
        {dateState.toLocaleString("eu-DE", {
          hour: "numeric",
          minute: "numeric",
          second: "numeric",
          hour12: false
        })}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-70423606-4umr2

Comment: Thank you for your help and your codesnippet. React isn't as easy as I thougth it would be but i appreciate the help I received here. I should really start using stackoverflow more often :D